# My gas pedal is not responding

Tags: ford, explorer

I have a 2007 Ford Sport Track Explorer and I am getting codes P2104 and P2111. I replaced the throttle body sensor and the throttle motor but it is still messes up.

Is there anything you can help me with?

Comment: What does "it is still messes up" mean? What is the vehicle doing?

Comment: Have you picked up a OBD2 (OnBoard Diagnostics) Tool?  Some of the feed channels you can monitor are pedal position and Throttle Position Sensor (TPS).  You can verify things are working as intended, even when vehicle is not running.  [Here is a nice one, $31USD, works on both Android and Iphone](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B073XKQQQW)  Link this with free app "Car Scanner."  Possible wiring problem?  when you can read the input and output sensors you can see what's going on...

Comment: Do you have transmission fluid in there

Comment: Did you clear the codes after parts replacement? See if any re-set?